# Помогите решить задачу по Python

Tags: python

1. Пользователь вводит трёхзначное число
2. Находим каждую цифру числа
3. Определяем максимальную цифру
4. Определяем минимальную цифру
5. Выполняем вычисления в зависимости от значений каждой цифры:

   a. Максимальное кратное двум - находим корень квадратный из введённого числа

   b. Минимальное кратное трём - находим корень кубический из введённого числа

---

Не понимаю как сделать 5-й пункт.

```
import math

n = int(input('Введите трёхзначное число: '))

a = (n // 10) // 10     # 1-ое число
b = (n // 10) % 10      # 2-ое число
c = n % 10              # 3-ье число

if a > b and a > c:       # Находим максимальное число
    print('Максимальное число = ',a)
elif b > a and b > c:
    print('Максимальное число = ',b)
else:
    print('Максимальное число = ',c)

if a < b and a < c:       # Находим минимальное число
    print('Минимальное число = ',a)
elif b < a and b < c:
    print('Минимальное число = ',b)
else:
    print('Минимальное число = ',c)
```

Comment: Что вы не понимаете? Как проверить число на кратность? Как найти корень из числа?

Answer (score 2):

Между прочим, минимальную и максимальную цифру возможно определить просто как

```
max_, min_ = max(a, b, c), min(a, b, c)   # или отдельные команды для max_ и для min_
```

Затем пункт 5 вашего задания может быть

```
if max_ % 2 == 0
    print("Корень квадратный = ", n ** (1/2))      # или math.sqrt(n)
if min_ % 3 == 0
    print("Корень кубический = ", n ** (1/3))
```

`**` есть оператор возведения в степень, квадратный / кубический корень возможно сделать так, как я написал.

---

Между прочим, вместо

```
a = (n // 10) // 10     # 1-ое число
b = (n // 10) % 10      # 2-ое число
c = n % 10              # 3-ье число
```

можно сделать

```
a, b, c = map(int, list(str(n)))
```

*Объяснение:*

Например когда `n == 123`, постепенно:

1. `str(123)` будет `"123"`, затем
2. `list("123")` будет список `["1", "2", "3"]`, затем
3. `map(int, ["1", "2", "3"])` применит функцию `int` к всякому элементу списка, т.е. получим список `[int("1"), int("2"), int("3")]`, т. е. список `[1, 2, 3]`, затем
4. `a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]` присвоит отдельные элементы списка переменным `a`, `b` и `c`.

Comment: Можно и без `list(str(n))` обойтись. Сначала `n = input('...')`, затем уже `a, b, c = map(int, n)`. Поскольку строка — это и так список символов.